# Pandas - delete rows based on multiple `or` conditions

Tags: python, pandas

Let's assume my dataframe looks like this:

```
emp_id, age, salary
39239, 32, 2000
11010, 33, 3232
...
```

I have a list of `emp_id`'s that I would like to drop from the dataframe. The list is over 200 long so multiple `or` filters would be too cumbersome.

Is there a way to filter by passing just a list of `emp_id`'s?

Comment: you are looking for `isin`

Comment: This smells like a dupe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [DataFrame.isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html):

```
df[~df['emp_id'].isin(bad_emp_ids_list)]
```

Comment: Yes you are right.